# Customize Angular theme with different layout & colors by using angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes

I want to create different themes with different colors and layout with angular. I want to use the theme and customize it as per user requirement. Want to create global CSS(sass file) and theme wise config files, so that we can easily manage theme wise CSS file.

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check https://coryrylan.com/blog/theming-angular-apps-with-css-custom-properties

Comment: Thank you. Helpful